# conditional logic in the header.php

Tags: php, wordpress, header, conditional-statements

So I am using Wordpress and I have to have a specific logo on a specific page. From research I have to use conditional logic to swap the existing logo with another depending on the current page. Everything I have tried seems to just break the theme.. Any help on guiding me in the correct direction? So basically every page except page_id=79 would have the same logo in the header.

```
<a id="logo" href="<?php echo home_url();  ?>">

<?php
if(!empty($options['use-logo'])) {
    $default_logo_id = (!empty($options['retina-logo'])) ? 'id="default-logo"' : null;          
    echo '<img '.$default_logo_id.' alt="'. get_bloginfo('name') .'" src="' . $options['logo'] . '" />';         
    if(!empty($options['retina-logo'])) echo '<img id="retina-logo" alt="'. get_bloginfo('name') .'" src="' . $options['retina-logo'] . '" />';
    } else { echo get_bloginfo('name'); }
?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php if ( is_page(79) ) { ?>

        What to displayed on page 79.

    <?php } else { ?>

        What will be displayed everywhere else. 

    <?php } ?>
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `get_queried_object_id();`

```
<a id="logo" href="<?php echo home_url();  ?>">

<?php
if(!empty($options['use-logo']) && get_queried_object_id() != 79) {
    $default_logo_id = (!empty($options['retina-logo'])) ? 'id="default-logo"' : null;          
    echo '<img '.$default_logo_id.' alt="'. get_bloginfo('name') .'" src="' . $options['logo'] . '" />';         
    if(!empty($options['retina-logo'])) echo '<img id="retina-logo" alt="'. get_bloginfo('name') .'" src="' . $options['retina-logo'] . '" />';
    } else { echo get_bloginfo('name'); }
?>
</a>
```

The url of your logo image is contained within `$options['logo']`. You should be able to modify this in the admin section of your WordPress installation (try looking in "Appearance -> Header").

Comment: Thanks for your input. It seems to work but where to I add the URL to my image? or do I have to create an ID first with the image I want?